# setting visibility=hidden to a button which is already hidden in javascript, does this create any issues?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple buttons on my page whose visibility set to hidden and a drop down with 8 options. Option 1 shows only Button1. If I change my option to 2 then I see only Button2,Button2_1. Button1 should be hidden.

So, I am hiding all the other buttons except the button related to the option selected from the drop-down.Like this:

```
switch(view_opts.value)
{
case '1':
        document.getElementById('but1').style.visibility = "visible"; 
        document.getElementById('but2').style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        document.getElementById('but2_1').style.visibility = "hidden"; 
        ................
        docuent.getElementById('but11').style.visibility = "hidden";
break;
 case '2':
 ............

}
```

In case '1', Button11 may already set to hidden but I am again setting that to hidden.

I am doing in this way because I don't know which button was showing on the page before switching to new option.

This is working now. Do I face any further issues by doing this? If so, do I face same issues with disabling a disabled button? Then, what could be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

No this will not.
If its visible then

```
document.getElementById('but2').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

will hide the button if its not it does not effect.

If its still giving error try to find another error.